# TypeError: Abstract models cannot be instantiated (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have abstract models `A` and `B` and a child model `C`.

```
class A(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=24)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class B(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=24)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

   def make_A(self):
      A(field1=self.field1).save()


class C(B):
    pass
```

If I try to run `C.make_A()` I get `TypeError: Abstract models cannot be instantiated` error. So I am forced to re-write `make_A` method on the child. Is there a way to write a method that instantiates `A` under abstract `B`?

Comment: Since `A` is abstract `A(field1=self.field1)` makes not much sense,

Comment: Exactly what is `.make_A` supposed to do? Why are you constructing an `A` in the first place?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem ```A``` is a logging model, B has a ```log(x)``` method that takes text as an argument and creates ```A``` record linked to ```B```.

Comment: but then why is `A` abstract?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Because I inherit it multiple times in different apps, same as B. I have a ```models.py``` file in one app that I only use for templates and multiple apps that inherit from it. Now it seems that I will have to copy/paste ```make_A``` in every other app, and I was wondering if there's a shortcut for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that `B` is abstract, the problem is that `A` is abstract. But you can make a "template method", that you then slightly alter in `C` with:

```
class B(models.Model):
    concrete_A = None
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=24)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def make_A(self):
        self.concrete_A.objects.create(field1=self.field1)


class C(B):
    concrete_A = SubA
```

With `SubA` a *concrete* subclass of `A`.

That being said, given I understand what you aim to do, you seem to just to some extent replicate what [**`django-simple-history`** <sup>[readthedocs.io]</sup>](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is doing.